# PHP dynamically naming and accessing variables

Tags: php, variables

```
$var1 = 'First Variable';
$var2 = 'Second Variable';
$var3 = 'Third Variable';

$number = 2;

$variable_to_get = 'var'.$number;
```

Lets say you want to echo out a variable depending on what $number is; e.g. in this case $number is 2 so we want to echo out $var2. How would you go about doing this without using switch statements / ifs; just directly naming a variable and showing the result?

Comment: just use an array, it's the simplest way to me. Just to refresh your memory [PHP Array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

variable variable

```
echo ${'var'.$number};
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, braces maybe?   ${'var'.$number}  just a guess

Answer (score 1):

You would better use array.

```
$var = array(
   'first variable',
   'second variable',
   'third variable',
);
```

So you will have your `$var` like this :

```
array (
    [0] => 'first variable',
    [1] => 'second variable',
    [2] => 'third variable',
)
```

Then to get the value :

```
$variable_to_get = $var[$number-1];
```

`$number` should be -1 because array started on index 0.

Another approach, you can assign its index directly.

```
$var[1] = 'first variable'
$var[2] = 'second variable'
$var[3] = 'third variable'
```

But if you really want that you access using

```
$var1 = 'First Variable';
$var2 = 'Second Variable';
$var3 = 'Third Variable';

$number = 2;

$variable_to_get = 'var'.$number;
```

Try to use [eval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
$var = array('First Variable','Second Variable','Third Variable');


$variable_to_get = 'var'.$var[0]; // returns First Variable

$variable_to_get = 'var'.$var[1]; // returns Second Variable
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use double $$ to access the variable names as the string in the second variable.
The second accesses the variable string, and the first accesses the variable named as the string:

```
$foo = 'bar';
$bar = 'foo';

echo $$foo; // echoes foo
```

meaning in your case:

```
$var1 = 'First Variable';
$var2 = 'Second Variable';
$var3 = 'Third Variable';

$number = 2;

$variable_to_get = 'var'.$number; //will contain the string 'var2'

echo $$variable_to_get; //echoes 'Second Variable'
```